# PHP SQL Query with != Selection of multiple entries

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that is calling the SQL database and telling it to select every row except for where the code column is free_checkout.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "extension WHERE `type` = '" . $this->db->escape($type) . "' AND code != 'free_checkout' ORDER BY code");
```

I have another row where the code column is subscription_checkout.

How do I add subscription_checkout to this SQL query so that it reads like

```
code != 'free_checkout' OR 'subscription_checkout'
```

^ I've tried that but that definitely doesn't work. I'm assuming this is a syntax issue.

Comment: Have you tried anything else, like a `IN` clause? Additionally, this is not a PHP problem

Comment: @Nico I mentioned PHP because it seems the syntax was slightly slightly different when dealing with SQL commands coming from a php file rather than from within PHPmyadmin - but I could be off there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example of proper syntax, from w3schools.

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City='Berlin' OR City='München';
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

Basically you need to rewrite your piece to:

```
code != "free_checkout" AND code != "subscription_checkout"
```

Comment: Please think about that solution again. This will also return rows that contain `free_checkout` and those that contain `subscription_checkout`

Comment: This is not what is asked for. OP is looking for a shorter notation of `code != 'foo' AND code != 'bar' AND code != 'foobar' AND ...` - Your query above will select ALL results in the table because `subscription_checkout` doesn't equal `free_checkout` and the other way round

Comment: He specifically said OR